# Exclude from brunch build devDependencies node_modules

Tags: brunch

I'm using both bower and npm for external libraries in my app.

- bower.json contains all the application dependencies (backbone, lodash, etc...)
- package.json contains all the dev environment deps (babel, brunch, brunch plugins, etc...)

Here's part of my brunch-config.coffee file:

```
module.exports = config:
    files:
        javascripts:
            exclude: '/**/*.min.js'
            joinTo:
                'js/app.js': /^app/
                'js/vendor.js': /^(bower_components|vendor)/
```

And the, my brunch build does not embed node_modules (which are dev dependencies *only*).

I would like to remove bower and to make it all happen with npm. Is there a way in brunch to exclude from brunch build node_modules that are initially mentioned in the 'devDependencies' section of the package.json?

Thanks a lot,

Pierre (frontend beginner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brunch automatically detects packages you are using in your application. No action is required from you. If there are 10 brunch plugins and 2 babel addons, Brunch won't use them unless you write `require('babel')` in your frontend code.

Comment: Clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems valid when using `entryPoints`, but when using `joinTo` it matches all files whether required/imported or not. (I know this discussion is old, and things might have changed over time)